# How do we convert boolean to string in Haskell

Tags: haskell, boolean

I'm a beginner in Haskell. I was trying to add a string into a list, and this string should contains either `"TRUE"` or `"FALSE"` depending on the conditions.

```
type Output = [String]
type T = Bool 

f :: T -> [String]
```

I was trying to use `printf` here, but I don't know the symbol for bool type(like `%d` for int) . Is there any good ways to do this? Thanks!

Comment: It is quite unclear if you just want to convert Bool to String (as the title suggests), or have problems with `printf`, or the list of strings. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a function which turns a single `Bool` into a single `String`:

```
boolToString :: T -> String
boolToString True = "TRUE"
boolToString False = "FALSE"
```

but it's not clear from your question what the other parts of the `[String]` should be.

Comment: It's a list to store the outputs. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 9):

How about a plain if expression?

```
if condition then "TRUE" else "FALSE"
```

Alternatively, if you do not care about the upper case, you could just use `show` on a boolean.

Answer (score 5):

You can define a function based on the `show` function that is defined for `Bool`:

```
import Data.Char(toUpper)

showBool :: Bool -> String
showBool = map toUpper . show
```

Since `show` returns `True` or `False`, by using the `map toUpper` function, you put all in uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

You can't turn a `Bool` into a `[String]`, just into a `String`.

You should do something like:

```
toString :: T -> String {-  T = Bool (It was a type defined by him-}
toString x = if x then "True" else "False"
```

If you really want the result to be `[String]` you can just do:

```
toString :: T -> [String] 
toString x = if x then ["True"] else ["False"]
```

Comment: You can turn a `Bool` into a list of `String`s. Not only that, but there are an infinite number of ways to turn a `Bool` into a list of `String`s (even if we only count lists that only consist of the strings `"TRUE"` and "`FALSE"`)!

Comment: You can just change the `"True"` into `["True"]` for example.

Comment: @Ash: ok, no problem with this `T`. +1 btw.